# IPad app launch timeout

Tags: ios, timeout, launch

I'm developing an IPad application that use a prefeatched database with a synchronisation feature of course, when the app start, it checks for the existence of its database on Document directory, if database doesn't exists the application copy its database from ressource file to document directory.

when I start testing the application with a smaller database (< 300 MB) the application start correctly, but when I test it with the real database (5 GB) the application is stopped due to timeout

can anyone have an idea of how to increase the launch timeout for the application? is there another approch to do database copy without having to deal with this problem?

Thank's in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should present the UI to the user as soon as possible and then start copying the database on background thread.

Comment: +1 I did usability testing on iphone and found that users begin to interpret a launch time longer than 5 seconds as a hang and longer than 10 as a freeze/crash. They will tolerate longer launch times on iPad but not by much. In any case, launch to an initial screen and if you have to do a long load, tell the user that is what is going on. Otherwise, they will think your app buggy.

Answer (score 1):

5 GB is quite a sizable database. If you intend to distribute this app over the App Store, then you should be aware that the download limit for App Store apps is 2 GB.

Comment: we are deploying our application with In house strategy, so we will not use App Store, but is there any physical size limitation on IPad application? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the launch timeout because that is a system function. Instead, you need to change when you do the load as [fichek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877465/fichek) suggested.